# Javascript disables modal popup button in bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

**JSFiddle DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/2yx16k8L/

I need this JS code to be able to open the entire DIV when clicked. However, this disables the modal button in the dropdown. It won't open the modal anymore.

How do I go about this?

HTML:

```
<div class="project__body" onclick="location.href='next.html';">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-10">
      <h1>Title of the DIV!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 text-right">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button type="button" class="dropdown-btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu</button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="edit.html">Edit</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="delete.html">Delete</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">Copy</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <p>There's more content here in this div. There's more content here in this div. There's more content here in this div. </p>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal">Title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">x</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Body of the modal
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
$('.dropdown').click(function(event) {
  $(this).children(".dropdown-menu").toggle()
  event.stopPropagation();
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this:

```
$(".dropdown-item[data-target='#modal']").click(function(){
    $("#modal").modal("show");
});
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/q31juvra/

Comment: and also add attribute disbaled inside the click event   $(this).attr("disabled", "");

Comment: @rrsantos is that necessary?

Comment: yes because the question is Javascript disables modal popup button in bootstrap 4 He wants to disabled the modal button when its clicked and not abled  to click anymore.

Comment: @rrsantos. I don't think so.

Comment: ah ok i misunderstand the question hhahah